# Insert form php on same page & select options as table

Tags: php, insert, html-select

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("nature")or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

?>

    <div class="submitrabble">
        <div class="sbttitle" >
            <span>Submit link to nature</span>
        </div>  
        <form id="submit" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
            <select name="topic" class="picktopic" >
                <option value="">Pick Topic</option>
                <option value="tress">Trees</option>
                <option value="mountains">Mountains</option>
                <option value="oceans">Oceans</option>
                <option value="animals">Animals</option>
            </select>   
            <br>
            <br>
        <textarea name ="title" class="submittitle" type="text"  maxlength="200" placeholder="Title" style="text-transform:capitalize;"></textarea><br><br>
        <textarea name="url" class="submiturl" type="text"  maxlength="200" placeholder="URL" style="text-transform:capitalize;"></textarea><br><br>
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" />

        </form>
        </div>
```

Anyone know how to insert select option as table and process submit on same page?

I'm trying to have user send title with links on the bottom section.
http://naturelink.net76.net/

DB -nature
Tables - Trees, Mountains, Oceans, Animals.
Row - Tree_id, Tree_title, Tree_url, timestmp, datestamp.(same format with other tables)

Comment: table(trees) row is trees_id, trees_title, trees_url, timesubmit, datesubmit.

Comment: are you trying to insert three fields submitted from your form into database?

Comment: DB should be "nature" not trees. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: you can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

1. Add a hidden field to your form and name it to whatever you want and assign it a value. I've named it 'status' and given it a value of 'submitted'.
2. On submitting the form, post the form values back to the same file, and check if the hidden form value has the value you assigned to it. This value is only set when you submit the form, so you can use this to identify whether to show the form or process the values (and insert into the database) once the form is submitted.
3. Make everything PHP so you can either display/not display the form.

Your code would then look something like this. Note I made the action on the form blank. This will post the form values back to the same file. What you had should work as well though.

```
?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("nature")or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['status'])){

if (strcmp($_POST['status'], "submitted") == 0)
{

//I'm not checking if these values are set. You can do that :)
$topic =  $_POST['topic'];
$title =  $_POST['title'];
$url =  $_POST['url'];


//do your validation of form fields and database processing here...
}
else
{
   //form not submitted so display it

echo '
 <div class="submitrabble">
    <div class="sbttitle" >
        <span>Submit link to nature</span>
    </div>  
    <form id="submit" action="" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="submitted" />

        <select name="topic" class="picktopic" >
            <option value="">Pick Topic</option>
            <option value="tress">Trees</option>
            <option value="mountains">Mountains</option>
            <option value="oceans">Oceans</option>
            <option value="animals">Animals</option>
        </select>   
        <br>
        <br>
    <textarea name ="title" class="submittitle" type="text"  maxlength="200" placeholder="Title" style="text-transform:capitalize;"></textarea><br><br>
    <textarea name="url" class="submiturl" type="text"  maxlength="200" placeholder="URL" style="text-transform:capitalize;"></textarea><br><br>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Submit" />

    </form>
    </div>

    ';
   }
 }

?>
```